# tkinter overrideredirect can't quit

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


def close_escape(event=None):
    print('pressed')
    window.overrideredirect(False)
    window.destroy()


# window
window = tk.Tk()
window.title('window')

# security event
window.bind('<Escape>', close_escape)
# window.bind('<Escape>', lambda event: window.quit())
# window.bind('<Escape>', lambda event: window.destroy())
# window.bind('<Escape>', lambda event: print('esc'))
window.after(3000, window.destroy)

# title bar
window.overrideredirect(True)

# run
window.mainloop()
```

python 3.12, MacOS 14.1.2, tkinter 8.6

None of the security event with bind work.
I find someone said on Mac and linux may remove events sanding from system to the program.

**Are there any way of removing the title bar and still being able to close the app?**

I know if I put title as nothing it kind of gives me the same result though.

Saw someone use ('-type', 'splash') to get a splash screen.
Not the case and not showing any effect here...

Also, not looking for fullscreen solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give the window the keyboard focus so that it gets keyboard events.

```
...
# title bar
window.overrideredirect(True)
window.after_idle(window.focus_force)
...
```

Comment: A huge thanks to you, it finally worked! I search for more than 50 webpage to find the answer and get nothing.